# How to create a cipher string that doesn't contain AES and CAMELLIA ciphers?

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection

I am trying to learn about cipher lists and how to order them. I am new to this. I have gone through this [doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html). I don't get some of the things mentioned in it. Maybe this post can clairfy it.

I want to create a cipher list that doesn't contain AES and CAMELLIA ciphers.

Does the following cipher string cover my use case? I don't have any idea.

```
openssl ciphers -v "ECDHE"
```

From the output of the command, it does contain AES and CAMELLIA ciphers. So maybe the above cipher string is wrong.

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM8(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESCCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA256
```

Please can anyone guide what the cipher string should be ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable AES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a cipher list that doesn't contain AES and CAMELLIA ciphers.
>
> Does the following cipher string cover my use case? I don't have any
> idea.
>
> ```
> openssl ciphers -v "ECDHE"
> ```

This string has exactly nothing to do with what you want to achieve. This strings is about ciphers using ECDHE as a **key exchange** - which includes some ciphers using AES and CAMELLIA but not all of these. AES and CAMELLIA are symmetric ciphers, i.e. they are used for **encryption** using the previously (for example with ECDHE) exchanged key.

If you want to exclude AES based ciphers use `!AES`. And similar for CAMELLIA use `!CAMELLIA`. Or together

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!AES:!CAMELLIA'
```

Note that this does not cover TLS 1.3 ciphers yet - for this you would need explicitly select which ciphers to use instead of disabling all AES ciphers:

```
openssl ciphers -ciphersuites 'TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256' -v 'ALL:!AES:!CAMELLIA'
```